# adobe premiere fails to import "one" footage, but works fine importing "two or more", why?

Tags: adobe, adobe-premiere

whenever I try to drag a file into adobe premiere timeline, the mouse pointer turns in to a "you cant do it" shape and I cannot put "one single media" in my timeline. but as soon as i choose two or more media and drag them into the time line, everything is fine. can anybody help me why this happens? its so annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem for every files?
it's weird but you may try clearing cache, Go to Preferences> Media Cache and click delete.
if not works try:
restart your pc
close and reopen premiere (The most useful method)
test with other projects

and also check if you can drag it into project panel
if you can't, try another file that already worked.
hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).